# Why 'keySet' change when hashtable changing?

Tags: java, hashtable, keyset

When i read Hashtable in the source code (jdk 1.7). I found:

```
/**
 * Returns a {@link Set} view of the keys contained in this map.
 * The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are
 * reflected in the set, and vice-versa.  If the map is modified
 * while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through
 * the iterator's own <tt>remove</tt> operation), the results of
 * the iteration are undefined.  The set supports element removal,
 * which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the
 * <tt>Iterator.remove</tt>, <tt>Set.remove</tt>,
 * <tt>removeAll</tt>, <tt>retainAll</tt>, and <tt>clear</tt>
 * operations.  It does not support the <tt>add</tt> or <tt>addAll</tt>
 * operations.
 *
 * @since 1.2
 */
public Set<K> keySet() {
    if (keySet == null)
        keySet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new KeySet(), this);
    return keySet;
}
```

can you explain when why i do HashTable.put(),the KeySet cahnges.

the examples :

```
    Hashtable<String,Integer> hashtable=new Hashtable<>();
    hashtable.put("1",1);
    hashtable.put("2",1);
    hashtable.put("3",1);
    Set set= hashtable.keySet();
    set.size();
    hashtable.put("4",4);
    Set set1= hashtable.keySet();
```

when i debug to 'hashtable.put("4",4)',keyset object in the HashTable is not null. i debug in here:
[debuging img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrp68.png)

when run the 'count++'. keyset will change. why???

Comment: The keyset changed because the hastable changed. Unclear what you're asking, or at least what's obscure about that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the javadoc:

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

Your code changes the map, and the changes to the map are reflected in the set.

In short, the keyset changes because the javadoc says that it *should* change.

(Perhaps you don't understand what "reflect" means *in this context* ...)

Comment: Just now,I know it throughs Iterator contact the table's change.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say.